# Undefined function or variable "number" in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

```
 function parameter=CPTValues(index,sizes,CPTS)
   m=size(index,2);
   n=size(sizes,2);
   for i=m:1
       number=(round(index(1,i)-1))*arraySizes(sizes,n);
       n=n-1;
   end
   parameter=CPTS(round(number));
end

function arraySize=arraySizes(array,length)
   count=1;
    if (length>=2)
        for i=length-1:1
           count=count*round(array(1,i));
        end
        arraySize=round(count);
    else
        arraySize=1;
    end
end
```

Hi all, I try to write a function in Matlab to refer to a value in a multi-dimensional Matrix. When I have this function, and I try to pass the index=[2,1,2], sizes=[3,2,2] BP(a 3-dimensional matrix I have already defined) into my CPTValues function, I get the error:

`"Undefined function or variable "number" "`

Is there anybody here could help me with that, 
Thanks a lot~

here is a example of the CPTs
   %P_\theta(HD|CH,BP,G)

```
  HD=zeros(2,2,2,2);
  for i=1:m
      for ch=1:2
          for bp=1:2
              for g=1:2
                for hd=1:2
                    if(Data(i,5)==ch&&Data(i,4)==bp&&Data(i,2)==g&&Data(i,9)==hd)
                        HD(ch,bp,g,hd)=HD(ch,bp,g,hd)+1;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
PCBG=zeros(2,2,2);
for i=1:m
    for ch=1:2
        for bp=1:2
            for g=1:2
                if(Data(i,5)==ch&&Data(i,4)==bp&&Data(i,2)==g)
                    PCBG(ch,bp,g)=PCBG(ch,bp,g)+1;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

for ch=1:2
    for bp=1:2
        for g=1:2
            HD(ch,bp,g,:)=HD(ch,bp,g,:)/PCBG(ch,bp,g);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: can you give an example of the CTPS matrix, so we can test the function?

Comment: Note that your second for loop also does nothing if length >2

Answer (score 1):

The for goes from `i=m:1` , but matlab does not understand that `i` must decrease instead of increase! change the for line to for `i=m:-1:1` , it will do it.

EDIT2:

It works ok for me:

```
%Create random BP of sizes=[3,2,2]
BP=rand(sizes)
BP(:,:,1) =
    0.9572    0.1419
    0.4854    0.4218
    0.8003    0.9157
BP(:,:,2) =
    0.7922    0.0357
    0.9595    0.8491
    0.6557    0.9340
%Set an index to look
index=[2,1,2];
%try the function
CTPValues(index,sizes,BP)
    ans =
        0.9572
%try indexing the matrix directly
BP(2,1,2)
  ans =
    0.9595
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now this method can run but cannot give me the answer I want. It should give me the answer 0.875 but it returns 0 to me. There must be some questions about my method. Can u help me again? I just want to get the value of a multi array. Thanks in advance

Comment: for the second for loop, I think it does"count=count*round(array(1,i));" when the length is larger than two.

Comment: @lexie what are you triying to achieve with this piece of code? Just get the value inside a multidimensional array? why dont you directly 'CTPS(index)' ?

Comment: I know I could use the index, but the professor asks to write a method to write a single
method that will access any entry of any CPT with any
number of parents in time linear in the number of parents. This is what I want to achieve with this code

Comment: @lexie, Ok, I'll try to check it. Please, can you post a REAL part of your code? I can't run the last piece you posted as it is missing Data and m at least.